# Aggrid-treeGrid: Error: No component factory found for DetailPanelComponent

Tags: treeview, ag-grid

I am using angular 6.1, node 8.11.3 and i am trying to implement treeview with master details, same example provided here https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview. However I  am getting below error and master detail component s not rendering on expansion of row details.

```
MasterComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: No component factory found for DetailPanelComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3258)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:3293)
    at Ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.js.Ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.createComponent (ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.js:66)
    at DynamicAgNg2Component.createComponent (ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.js:45)
    at DynamicAgNg2Component.push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.js.BaseGuiComponent.init (ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.js:85)
    at DynamicAgNg2Component.init (ng2FrameworkComponentWrapper.js:41)
    at ComponentResolver.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentResolver.js.ComponentResolver.initialiseComponent (componentResolver.js:295)
    at ComponentResolver.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentResolver.js.ComponentResolver.createAgGridComponent (componentResolver.js:246)
    at rowComp.js:673
    at rowContainerComponent.js:58
```

I am following exactly same thing as mention in example, but for Angular 6.

Please suggest.

Comment: please provide working plnkr-url, to get it: open the plnrk, write your sample and then click the 'Save' button and post url here again.

Comment: Thanks. This got resolved. I missed to add this into app.module.ts